# On the ring $R[X]/(X^q - g)$ being regular

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, regular-rings

Let $R$ be a Noetherian  domain of finite Krull dimension. Let $0\ne g \in R$ be such that $R/gR$ is reduced. let $q$ be a positive integer.

Is the following true: $R[X]/(X^q - g)$ is a regular ring if and only if $R$ and $R/gR$ are regular ?

Note: A ring is called regular iff localisation at every prime ideal is regular local ring.

If needed, I'm willing to assume $R$ contains an algebraically closed field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $R=k[x,y]$ and $g=xy$. Then $R[z]/(z-xy) \cong k[x,y,z]/(z-xy)$ is regular, but $R/gR \cong k[x,y]/(xy)$ is not.

Comment: I see ... possibly it is true if $(g)$ is a prime ideal in $R$ ?

Comment: @uno No. Let $R=k[x,y]$ and $g=x^2+y^3$.  Then $R[z]/(z-x^2-y^3) \cong k[x,y,z]/(z-x^2-y^3)$ is regular, but $R/gR \cong k[x,y]/(x^2+y^3)$ is not.